# Closed form for $\sum_{i=1}^n{a^{i^2}}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, closed-form-expressions, exponential-sums

Let $a$ be an element of some ring or field, possibly finite.

Is there closed form for $\sum_{i=1}^n{a^{i^2}}$?

sage and wolframalpha couldn't solve it.

If $a$ is primitive n-th root of unity this is Gauss sum and the result is $\sqrt{n}$ or $i\sqrt{n}$ for odd prime $n$.

Comment: You mean, if $a$ is a *primitive* $n$-th root of unity.

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify in what class of expressions you consider a "closed form""?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks, indeed. I edited.

Answer (score 3):

Some partial information.

If $g$ is a primitive root modulo prime $p$, then for $p\equiv 3
\pmod{4}$ $$\sum\limits_{x=1}^{p-1}g^{x^2}\equiv
0\pmod{p}.$$

If $p\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ and
$$S_1=\sum\limits_{x=1}^{p-1}g^{x^2},\quad
S_2=\sum\limits_{x=1}^{p-1}g^{-x^2}$$ then
$$S_1S_2+2\equiv 0\pmod{p}.$$

Sorry, I forget the source. Probably one can find related things in the papers of Arne Winterhof. For example he studied [A Polynomial Representation of the Diffie-Hellman Mapping.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00200-002-0104-2)

Comment: Thanks. The general case is hopeless, so only partial results are possible.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of a closed form for this finite series.  For an **infinite** series like this, we can use a Jacobi theta function
$$
\vartheta_3\left( z,q \right) =1+2\,\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{q}^{
{n}^{2}}\cos \left( 2\,nz \right)
$$
with $z=0$.

Comment: Thanks, probably other thetas might give similar results.